# Recording Video at 25 Frames per second in iOS

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, recording, avassetwriter

Im doing a custom camera to film at Full HD or just HD quality. The issue is that after I set the Camera to 25 Frames with the follow code:

```
- (void) setFrameRate:(AVCaptureDevice*) camera {
    NSError *error;
    if (![camera lockForConfiguration:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Could not lock device %@ for configuration: %@", camera, error);
        return;
    }
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format = camera.activeFormat;
    double epsilon = 0.00000001;
    int desiredFrameRate = 25;
    for (AVFrameRateRange *range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges) {
        if (range.minFrameRate <= (desiredFrameRate + epsilon) &&
            range.maxFrameRate >= (desiredFrameRate - epsilon)) {
            [camera setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(10, desiredFrameRate*10)];
            [camera setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(10, desiredFrameRate*10)];
            break;
        }
    }
    [camera unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

It changes the video fps but not to exactly 25 frames per second like I set in method. It fluctuate between 23.93 and 25.50 frames per second.
Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1):

After several attempts and debugging I find out that the issue with the frame rate not being exactly 25 frame has to do with the recording method and not wiht the device setup.

I was using AVAssetWriter object to record the video like the example showed in the follow link (https://reformatcode.com/code/ios/ios-8-film-from-both-back-and-front-camera).

But in no way was possible to get the exactly 25 fps.

Change the object for recording video for AVCaptureMovieFileOutput and was supper easy from there setting up and recording. Result its much more precise, between 25 and  25.01.